# How to configure Eclipse Project for Joomla Component Development

Tags: php, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, include-path

I like to develop a fresh Joomla Component for Joomla 3.x in Eclipse and created therefore a simple PHP project.

The problem I have is now how to setup the correct "include path", so that the basic Joomla PHP classes get found like "JFactory" , "JAccess", "JObject" ...

If I just include a Joomla installation in my include path, this will not work. I assume the paths to the classes are more sophisticated than that.

Any Idea or suggestion how the "include path" for my project should look like?

regards
Mark

Comment: I don't know how to help, but there may be volunteers who can help at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little on what you mean by "found".

If you mean "as I start typing a basic class name every matching basic class gets offered as an option", yes, there is a way to do that.

See the conversation, and solution, on [this gitHub page](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/16289).

I have the stub file referred to and it works in the way I've said above, tho' I'm using NetBeans not Eclipse (but the reference to phpStorm makes me think it should/could work for you too), although I haven't been able to run the build script. I just haven't got the time to single step through it to find out where it stops.